# Trigger click function on element with id if handler is attached to class

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I would like to know if I can trigger a `.click` handler which is attached via class when I try to call it with id.
For example:

```
<div class="item" id="first">
<div class="item" id="second">
<div class="item" id="third">
```

and have an `.click` like

```
$('.item').click(someFunction);
```

what I now intend to do is, I want to use `.trigger('click');` if I click on a specific id.
When I do:

```
$('#third').trigger('click');
```

it won't work since the click is attached to the `class="item"`.

But is there a selector which makes it possible? Something like `$('.item#third')` that it triggers the click only when I click on an `.item` with the id `#third`.

Hope you get my point.

Comment: that will work!!! have you tried it

Comment: [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ehgygxdg/1/) - you need to register the handler first then trigger the event - the handlers are not attached to a selector, it is attached to the dom element

Comment: @ArunPJohny thank you, because of an external file it seems that the trigger got called before the handler. Didn't noticed until I used a timeout to make sure everything was loaded before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @ArunPJohny's demo code in the comments, here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.item').click(function () {
        console.log('clicked', this.id)
    });

    $('#third').trigger('click');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/ehgygxdg/2/)